# Robot Control Algorithms for Precise Positioning

Tags: ros2, pid, microcontroller, teb-local-planner, dwa-local-planner

I am currently researching the optimal controller algorithm to navigate my robot to a specific x and y position within a specific coordinate frame with a high degree of accuracy, approximately 5mm. Should I consider a path planning approach, such as utilizing a Pure Pursuit controller or MPII, without concern for obstacle avoidance since this is intended for a final docking procedure? Alternatively, would it be more suitable to employ a PID controller to control linear and angular velocity to reach the target position? What would be the most effective approach to meet my requirements?